# C++ Any way to store different templated object into the same container

Tags: c++, templates

Is there any hack I could use to do this:

```
template <class TYPE>
class Hello
{
     TYPE _var;
};
```

I would like a way to store

```
Hello<int> intHello and Hello<char*> charHello
```

into the same Container such as a Queue / List.

Comment: What end result are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, because they are different and completely unrelated types.

You can, however, use inheritance and smart pointers:

```
class HelloBase 
{
public:
    virtual ~HelloBase(); 
}

template <class TYPE>
class Hello : public HelloBase
{
    TYPE _var;
}

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<HelloBase> > v;
```

`shared_ptr` may be supported by your implementation either in the `std::tr1` or `std` namespace; you'd have to check.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, sort of -- but you probably don't want to. Even though they start from the same template, `Hello<int>` and `Hello<char *>` are completely separate and unrelated types.  A collection that includes both is heterogeneous, with all the problems that entails.

If you insist on doing this anyway, to do it reasonably cleanly, you'd typically create something like a queue/list of [`Boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/any.html).

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the real question: what are you trying to achieve (at a higher level) ?

Now, for this peculiar question there is a number of alternative. Containers cannot store heterogeneous data, so you can:

- give all `Hello<T>` a common base class and add virtual methods, then use pointers, take care of memory ownership (`unique_ptr` or `boost::ptr_list` would be great)
- if there is a precise set of types, use `boost::variant`, it's statically checked so you have reasonable guarantees
- else you should consider wrapping it into a storage class which would use `boost::any` under the covers

The common base class is the usual approach in this situation. If there is no reason to have polymorphism, then use preferably `variant` and if nothing else `any`.

Comment: I think this is a very good answer. I was missing variant on the other ones. To it seems like the preferred way.